# Can I install Ubuntu 20.04 on my D) hard drive and leave my SSD C drive for windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows, ssd

The question pretty much explains it but I want to make sure because this might make me delete everything by accident.

I have 128 GB SSD C drive, and 1 TB HDD drive on my laptop. Can I shrink the 1 TB and have Ubuntu installed on the shrunk amount?

Would that cause any problems?

My specs:
16 GB RAM
128 SSD
1 TB HDD
GTX 950

Comment: That should be fine. I think the installer will want to use some space on the ssd by default so use the something else option at the partitioning step to specify where to install. Make the space on the HDD with Windows disk manager first. I’d recommend backing up any data you cannot afford to loose and watching a couple of YouTube install guides as well.

Comment: Would suggest installing Ubuntu on to a VM like virtualbox, for now.  You can then test it out and do not have to worry about making mistakes.  Ubuntu is quite happy to be installed almost anywhere, but we all can make mistakes and delete data/OS we wanted to keep.  Can google installing Ubuntu and find more information, before installing.  Double check everything and go slow.